# How to add a Django form field dynamically depending on if the previous field was filled?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Form (Formset) for users to update their profiles. This is a standard User model form, and custom Participants model form. Now, in cases when a participant provide his phone number, I need to refresh the whole Form with a new 'Code' filed dynamically. And the participant will type the code he received my SMS.
Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        seller_form = SellerForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.object.seller)
        if seller_form.is_valid():
            seller = self.request.user.seller
            seller.inn = seller_form.cleaned_data.get('inn')
            if seller_form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number'):
                seller_form.fields['code'] = models.CharField(max_length=4)
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'seller_form': seller_form})
            seller.save()
            return HttpResponse('Seller updated')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'seller_form': seller_form})
```

Well I am not sure if this is the way I can add additional field. What would you suggest to handle this situation?

Comment: I think it should be done with javascript or htmx. Do you use any of them already?

Comment: No, I didn't try JS. I thought it is possible without JS.

Comment: I don't think so, at least I didn't find such solution. I suggest to go here https://htmx.org/ . It will give you much opportunities in the future and you use it almost as simple as html.

Answer (score 1):

A technique I have used is to have an initially hidden field on the form. When the form otherwise becomes valid, I cause it to become visible, and then send the form around again. In class-based views and outline:

```
class SomeThingForm( forms.Modelform):
    class Meta:
        model=Thing
        fields = [ ...

    confirm = forms.BooleanField( 
        initial=False, required=False, widget=forms.widgets.HiddenInput,
        label='Confirm your inputs?' )

class SomeView( CreateView): # or UpdateView
    form_class = SomeThingForm
    template_name = 'whatever'

    def form_valid( self, form):

        _warnings = []
        # have a look at cleaned_data
        # generate _warnings (a list of 2-tuples) about things which
        # aren't automatically bad data but merit another look

        if not form.cleaned_data['confirm'] and _warnings:
            form.add_error('confirm', 'Correct possible typos and override if sure')
            for field,error_text in _warnings:
                form.add_error( field, error_text) # 'foo', 'Check me'
                # make the confirm field visible
                form.fields['confirm'].widget = forms.widgets.Select(
                    choices=((0, 'No'), (1, 'Yes')) )
            # treat the form as invalid (which it now is!)
            return self.form_invalid( form)

    # OK it's come back with confirm=True
    form.save()  # save the model
    return redirect( ...)
```

For this question, I think you would replace `confirm` with `sms_challenge`, a `Charfield` or `IntegerField`, initially hidden, with a default value that will never be a correct answer. When the rest of the form validates, `form_valid()` gets invoked, and then the same program flow, except you also emit the SMS to the phone number in cleaned_data.

```
        _warnings = [] 
        # retrieve sms_challenge that was sent
        if form.cleaned_data['sms_challenge'] != sms_challenge:
            _warnings.append( ['sms_challenge', 'Sorry, that's not right'] )
        if _warnings:
            ...
            form.fields['sms_challenge'].widget = forms.widgets.TextInput
            return self.form_invalid( form)
```

I think that ought to work.